# COUNT in MYSQL MULTIPLY ROW AND FILTER by date and ID

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have Table that record data from bar code with staff id and date i wish to get result by filtering data in one day such as

1. how many members
2. how many bar-codes

lets say in 2015/07/29,  two member read 33 bar-codes
but in database i have bar-code number the day of reading and id of member how do i filter that to give me in one row
I tried this one but result is

```
DATE          ID     total 
2015/07/29    1002   33
```

total is right but show only one id i need count total members in same day

```
select
yyyymmdd,
tanntou AS ID,
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM janru
WHERE (yyyymmdd = curdate())
GROUP BY yyyymmdd, tanntou
```

Comment: This question is unclear to me.

Comment: it seems you have single member on that date, plz show your data in table to verify this.

Comment: No pictures thanks. Just proper CREATE and INSERT statements - enough to be properly representative - and the desired result

Comment: i correctly add two ID 1002 and 3, 1002 read 25 data and 3 read 8 data i wish to add picture here but its my first post here i dont know how can i add picture in here
 
its showing only total of bar-code has been read and only one ID i need to see like DATE 2015 and total 33 and something like member 2 not only one ID

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `janru` (
  `barno` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `basic` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `gomi` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sexy` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tanntou` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `yyyymmdd` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `yobi` char(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: INSERT INTO `janru` (`barno`, `lux`, `street`, `casual`, `basic`, `gomi`, `sexy`, `tanntou`, `yyyymmdd`, `yobi`) VALUES
('99999999', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '2015/07/29', ''),
('999998', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3', '2015/07/29', '2007/03/29'),
('999999', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '3', '2015/07/29', '2007/03/13'),
('999997', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3', '2015/07/29', ''),
('999996', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3', '2015/07/29', ''),
('800003', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '2015/07/29', ''),
('3736092', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1002', '2015/07/29', ''),

Comment: its much longer i cant type here just insert some line its currectcly for tanntou 3 has 8 barno and for 1002 has 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer by add DISTINCT to COUNT

```
select
yyyymmdd,
COUNT(tanntou) AS `Total of Items`,
COUNT(DISTINCT tanntou) AS `Total of Members`
FROM janru
GROUP BY yyyymmdd
```